# get parameter without define in function get from route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

```
public function login($companyId="",$invoiceId="")
{

}
```

`$companyId` I want to fetch from URL get its working fine for me but here I want to get `$companyid` as `input::get`

```
public function login()
{
    $companyid = Input::get();
}
```

I am getting null becourse i cannot pass name in get() becouse i m fetching it from url so how can i achive it ........

```
value i have passed from route
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to look at your route definition. If your route is as

```
 Route::get('/login/{companyId?}/{invoiceId?}', array('as'=> 'login', function($companyId="",$invoiceId="") {}));
```

then remove those parameters and change it to

```
Route::get('/login', array('as'=>'login',function(){....}));
```

After that you can change your route call to

```
route('login', array('companyId'=> 1231323, 'invoiceId'=> 123123));
```

this arguments you passed in array will be query string. It is important to remove those dynamic segments from your Route definition.